# Performance issues when upgrading from ruby 1.9.3 to 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upgrade

When upgraded from ruby-1.9.3-p545 to ruby-2.2.2 we experienced a 50% drop in performance on our application. I have done a fair amount of reading around this and I suspect that this may be a result of the change in the way that ruby does garbage collection.

The confusing thing is that there have been no noticeable changes on our server metrics. We have not seen a spike in memory usage. If garbage collection was causing a performance slow down would we see a spike in memory usage ? Is this a sign that the performance issues are being caused elsewhere ? Possible by gems not playing nicely together ?

Comment: What have you done to track down the cause of this performance drop? Is it only affecting specific areas of the application? Could that lead to any clues, e.g. gems which are being heavily used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the cause of the performance drop related to garbage collection. We managed to realise a significant improvement in performance by setting `RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT=90000000`

We used the following as a resource
https://meta.discourse.org/t/tuning-ruby-and-rails-for-discourse/4126